# Listening to keyboard events in C#

Tags: c#, events, keyboard, keystrokes

Im building a small application for my employer where hitting a certain keystroke will display a model box containing information that one of our technicians would require when providing one to one support.

its a very simple application but tracking the keyboard events without causing any issues for the user is puzzling me.

Basically I need to write a class that I can rely on to send me an event when <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> are fired.

what's the best methods of completing this without having tons of events fired through my application, for example, ask windows to inform me when the keystroke has been entered.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [global hotkey](http://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/). The link contains a class that encapsulates the P/Invoke stuff required to use global hotkeys in .NET.

Comment: With the global hotkey, can I register an Application Context instead of a form?

Comment: Inside the `Hotkey` class, try passing `IntPtr.Zero` instead of `windowControl.Handle` to the `Hotkey.RegisterHotKey` method.

Comment: I haven't tried it as of yet, I have been looking into @mgronber's post

Comment: @RobertPitt: IMHO, the global hotkey is the better solution, because your requirement is exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ( http://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/globalhook.aspx ) for the Keyboard hook and then at where they show you how to listen for specific combinations ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/2b91129c-bcc4-4cd7-bf6b-25fb10629b8a ).

Hope that helps...